Optimize ETL glue job output writing to AWS S3 bucket, both DyamicDataframe and S3 being partitioned
I have a medium dataset, with about 1GB of data, which I'm reading, processing and saving into an AWS S3 bucket. The reading (also from S3) and processing of the data is quite fast, about 50 seconds (without machine initialization time). However, writing data to S3 takes so long, about 6 minutes.
The ETL code for saving the data is
    bucket_s3_final = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
            frame=df, 
            connection_type="s3", 
            connection_options={
                    "path": "s3://my_bucket/",
                    "partitionKeys": ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5'],
                    "groupFiles": "inPartition"
            }, 
            format="parquet",
        )

Each final folder has an average of 40 files, each with ~300KB of size. I don't understand why this is taking so long to write.
EDIT 1: Each file is about ~300KB, not 300MB as was written
